# Running Curl in Run Shell Script with arguments in Automator

Tags: bash, shell, curl, automator, ifttt

I'm trying to send a curl command in Automator via the 'Run Shell Script', with arguments, but having no luck. I'm using /bin/bash and passing info as arguments. Here is my script but keep getting `Bad Request` from IFTTT. I get it's to do with not using the args correctly (if I just put `"value1":"test"` it works fine), how should I format the $1?

```
for f
do
  curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"value1":$1}' https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/Automator/with/key/heremykey
done
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass a valid JSON. There is no built-in JSON support in Bash, so you need to use external tools, such as PHP, or Node:

```sh
#!/bin/bash -

function json_encode {
  printf "$1" | php -r 'echo json_encode(stream_get_contents(STDIN));'
}

for f
do
  value=`json_encode "$f"`
  curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"value1\":$value}" \
    https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/Automator/with/key/heremykey
done
```

The script is supposed to send `{"value1": ...}` string for each item in `$@`(because the short version of the `for` loop operates on `$@`).

Comment: Excellent, thank you! While we're at it, what's the best way to parse the $1 from `/folder/subfolder/subfolder/etc/etc/file.mp4` to `file.mp4`?

Comment: @PJPalomaki `basename "$1"`